# Uri Binding for Image in FrameworkElementFactory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, frameworkelementfactory

I am creating a DataTemplate in code and cannot use XAML. :(

I have managed to create an image inside the Template, but only if I hardcode the path to the ico file. I would love to be able to bind that string to the item (I am using the DataTemplate on a modified ListView).

Here's my code right now:

```
private DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate(string binding, HorizontalAlignment alignment, bool active, bool useIcon)
{
    DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();

    FrameworkElementFactory sp = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
    sp.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

    if (useIcon)
    {
        double size = 14.0;
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("MyIcon.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        FrameworkElementFactory icon = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
        icon.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, bmp);
        icon.SetValue(Image.WidthProperty, size);
        icon.SetValue(Image.HeightProperty, size);
        icon.SetValue(Image.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0));
        sp.AppendChild(icon);
    }

    FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(binding));
    tb.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, (active ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.Gray));
    tb.SetValue(TextBlock.TextTrimmingProperty, TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis);
    tb.SetValue(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, alignment);
    sp.AppendChild(tb);

    dt.VisualTree = sp;
    return dt;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Every time you use `FrameworkElementFactories` a cute kitten gets killed. (Could you explain to me why you cannot use XAML?)

Comment: I have a modified ListView which can be found at dev.stoffiplayer.com/source/browse/trunk/Application/GUI/Controls/ViewDetails.xaml and dev.stoffiplayer.com/source/browse/trunk/Application/GUI/Controls/ViewDetails.xaml.cs

In it I create columns dynamically (ie: they are not hardcoded) and I need to apply a DataTemplate to each CellTemplate property of the column. Since I don't know the fields of the underlying items or the bindings I need to do it in code instead of XAML.

If you have a suggestion to make the code prettier I would love to hear it. :)

Comment: I can't use FrameWorkElementFactory in my Visual Studio 2012 for windows Phone8. Is that Particular Functionality is only available for Ultimate Version????

Answer (score 2):

I suppose a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) could work.

```
public class StringToBitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string uristring = value as string;
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(uristring, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

```cs
icon.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding(path) { Converter = new StringToBitmapImageConverter() });
```

Where `path` is a property path which points towards the property holding an uri-string within the templated object.

Comment: Looks great. I'll test it soon. One question: will this update the image if the property is changed?

Comment: @H.B I can't use FrameWorkElementFactory in my Visual Studio 2012 for windows Phone8. Is that Particular Functionality is only available for Ultimate Version????

Comment: @Seven007: 1. `FrameworkElementFactory` is part of .NET which has nothing to do with the IDE software. 2. Windows Phone uses a subset of what is in the desktop version of WPF. 3. You should not try to use `FrameWorkElementFactory` anyway because it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

An `IValueConverter` is the solution here. Mind the pack URI syntax though!
In case the image is not part of your solution your `Convert` method should look like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   return "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/" + (string)value;
}
```

Note that the image files need to be in the same directory as your applications binary, or a subdirectory thereof, since leading `"../"`s will be stripped away automatically.